# G305 Wireless battery issues

Tags: logitech-mouse, wireless-mouse

This is the first time I had to change the battery on my mouse considering it is fairly new, but when i place in a new battery it just doesn't turn on at all, it only turns back on when I place in the old battery.

Comment: Are you sure the new battery is good? Did you install it the correct way around? Is the new battery making contact? Some AA / AAA batteries are a bit shorter than others.

Comment: Also check the positive terminal of the battery -- some battery holders are too narrow for the "bump", in which case widen the slot for the bump with a small file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what the issue was but apparently after trying every single battery in the box only about 2 of them didn't work with the mouse even though the box was brand new